# Mapview invalidate exception in listview

Tags: android, listview, width, android-mapview, point

when init the mapview the mapview can show some of the points in map.
when scroll the list  the mapview will show all of the points in map.
can anyone tell me how to make the mapview show all of the points in map?
the code in xml is as below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/pic_bg" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/trip_allspots_map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:apiKey="@string/harold_debug_apikey"
        android:clickable="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```